# BlueImp Jquery File Upload: don't send form data

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

So I'm using Blueimp jQuery file upload on a Wordpress website in combination with Advanced Custom Fields.
Once the form is submitted, ACF redirects the user to the payment gateway.
For ACF to know where to redirect the user, it adds a form field called "return" and that's where the URL is stored.

However, when I try to do the ajax upload (before even submitting the form), jquery file upload takes that url and tries to call it, for whatever reason.

Does anyone know can I avoid sending form data altogether and only send the input file field?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an update:
Blueimp jQuery File Upload does not actually submit the URL just because it's a URL. It tries to submit whatever exists in the "return" field.
I have no clue as to why, but I found a way around it.

At first, I tried using PUT instead of POST and that seemed to take care of that problem, but the $_FILES array was empty.
After that, I decided to hook my do_upload function into the *wp* hook instead of *wp_head*.
Now before any asks why would I ever think of using *wp_head*: if you hook into *init*, you run the risk of many Wordpress' dependencies not being load and therefore you wouldn't be able to use things like wp_handle_upload().

TL;DR: to avoid issues with Advanced Custom Fields and Blueimp jQuery Upload plugin, hook your upload function like this:

```
add_action("wp", "your_function_name");
```